# Python dissolve causes TopologyException error

Tags: python, geopandas

I am using the `dissolve` function to compress my geopandas dataframe into a smaller table with fewer rows. I have read online one way to fix an invalid polygon is to create a 0 buffer for its geometry objects. So I have done that. I have fixed some polygons but it still gives the same error for other polygons. Can anyone give some suggestions as to what else I can do to fix this error?

```
burn_grass['geometry'] = burn_grass.geometry.buffer(0)
burn_grass.is_valid.unique()
output:array([ True], dtype=bool)

burn_grass = burn_grass.dissolve(by=['UUID'], as_index=False)
```

output:

> TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 130.94262695312494 -19.395507812500028 at 130.94262695312494 -19.395507812500028
>       pandas/_libs/src\reduce.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.SeriesGrouper.get_result()

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect answer but it kind works around this issue for me. Also when I tested it performed faster than dissolve function.

So what I have done is to select multipolygon based on UUID and recreate gpd with the list of multipolygons.

```
burn_grass.index=burn_grass.UUID
fix = []
UUID_list = burn_grass.UUID.unique()
for i, id in enumerate(UUID_list):
    tmp = burn_grass[burn_grass['UUID']==id].geometry
    sh = MultiPolygon([x.buffer(0) for x in tmp.geometry])
    fix.append({'UUID': id, 'geometry':sh})
burn_grass = gpd.GeoDataFrame(fix, columns=['UUID', 'geometry'])
burn_grass = burn_grass.set_geometry('geometry')
burn_grass['geometry']=burn_grass.geometry.buffer(0)
burn_grass.crs = grid.crs
```